How to create a shortcut on the desktop from a file on my NAS (Synology)?
I'm trying to create a shortcut from my NAS to my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS desktop. I did a search on the internet, but unable to find a solution.
Thanks ahead for a solution (and how to do it)

Your question is not answerable as asked. Edit your question and add information about how you connect your desktop to the NAS. Depending on the protocol, it may be possible to create a bookmark (or a shortcut) inside the Files app for a folder in your NAS. If your NAS has a client app for Ubuntu, you may be able to sync a folder between Ubuntu and the NAS and create a symbolic link to that folder on your desktop.

[edit] your question to indicate which file system is being used on your synology NAS. Storage Manager > Volume Usage will tell you as well as how the share is mounted in fstab.

I'm using KDE desktop on Ubuntu, but I just made a dummy .desktop file to test this out. My desktop environment uses the Dolphin file explorer.
You want to make a .desktop file (I called this example test.desktop) and at a minimum have this in it:
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=dolphin /path/to/mounted/folder %u

Then you just paste this file in your /home/[user]/Desktop directory and the link will be on the desktop. If you want to add an icon, you can add an Icon tag and then link it to a image.
If you need to mount the folder to your Synology, you need to edit /etc/fstab. I use cifs (may need to apt install cifs-utils) for the connection type and have the NAS setup to do NFS connections with the highest possible version. I also suggest mounting the files in your home directory in a custom directory and setting the permissions so that only you can have access to them as /etc/fstab is visible to anyone. You also want to hide your security credentials in a file instead of hard typing them into your connection settings.
Example fstab setup:
//192.168.x.x/[Share-Folder-Name]    /path/to/mount/point  cifs credentials=/path/to/user/.cred,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-systemd.automount

x-systemd.automount helps with remounting it at boot so you don't have to manually mount it again.
